# Moved a Rails app to EC2 and now my file uploads get a Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, paperclip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a Rails app that has been live for over a year with no issues, running on a custom Ubuntu/Nginx/Puma setup.

Because of various issues with the hosting company, I moved the app over to EC2 this weekend - using ElasticBeanstalk on their Nginx/Puma/Ruby2.2 stack.

Everything is working fine - apart from file uploads.

The app itself uses the Paperclip gem for handling attachments - the actual files are only held momentarily in Paperclip, before being uploaded to a file-server controlled by my client (the very first version used S3 for storage, but now it uploads, attaches the "Job-Sheet" to the Job and then immediately uploads the "Job-Sheet" to the file-server).

As I say, this was all working fine on my old server.  But now, on EC2, I'm getting a Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8) error.

The job sheet itself can be an Excel file or a CSV.  It is defined as follows:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_attached_file :job_sheet
  validates_attachment_file_name :job_sheet, matches: [/csv\Z/, /xls\Z/, /xlsx\Z/]
  validates_attachment_presence :job_sheet
  ...
end
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @job = services['creates_job'].create_job job_params, session: current_session
    redirect_to jobs_path
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

The jobs_params does the StrongParams thing of permitting the parameters as required.

And the CreatesJob service object looks like:

```
def create_job params, session: nil
  ...
  job = services['jobs'].create! params.merge(code: code)
  ...
end
```

So apart from the fact that the actual logic is in a separate "CreatesJob" class, there's nothing unusual going on - pretty much a standard Rails/Paperclip upload situation.

However, some uploads are failing, with the following in the production log:

```
I, [2016-03-22T10:12:58.701172 #23116]  INFO -- : Started POST "/jobs" for 80.0.249.70 at 2016-03-22 10:12:58 +0000
F, [2016-03-22T10:12:58.706190 #23116] FATAL -- : Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/upload.rb:31:in `encode'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/upload.rb:31:in `initialize'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:51:in `new'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:51:in `normalize_encode_params'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:57:in `block in normalize_encode_params'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:53:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:53:in `each_with_object'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:53:in `normalize_encode_params'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:57:in `block in normalize_encode_params'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:53:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:53:in `each_with_object'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:53:in `normalize_encode_params'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:308:in `POST'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in `parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in `filtered_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.11.1.284) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:82:in `call'
  puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
  puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
  puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The other answers related to this error all seem to be about forcing the encoding of the file.  But the issue here seems to be 1) sometimes it's a binary (xls) and sometimes text (csv) so I can't go around mangling it and 2) the exception is in ActionDispatch; so looks like it's happening before I get to see the upload.

Any ideas what's going on and what I can do to fix it?

UPDATE: I can now reproduce the issue consistently.  If I upload an XLSX file with an English filename, the upload works OK, if it's an XLSX file with Spanish accented in the filename, the upload fails as shown above.

The line in question is @original_filename.encode!(Encoding::UTF_8) in action_dispatch/http/upload.rb - however, the filename should be valid unicode, but it's obviously getting mangled in transit somewhere.